# Revolt of Third World; South African gold mines nuked

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

In the 1980s (or perhaps, not likely, early 1990s) I read a book about a fictional future rise of the Third World. It wasn't well written and I don't remember much about it, but one detail was that apartheid South Africa still existed and was brought down by (nuclear?) explosions in its gold mines.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: One work that partially matches is _[The Warlord of the Air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlord_of_the_Air)_ and its sequel,  _[The Land Leviathan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Land_Leviathan)_, by Michael Moorcock.  Despite being partially set in South Africa, the nuke does not destroy South African gold mines, but they do figure into the plot.

Comment: It doesn’t quite fit, and is probably too recent (1991), but Larry Bond’s [*Vortex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_(Bond_and_Larkin_novel)) features nukes in South Africa, and the novel ends with the end of apartheid there.

Comment: The description of Larry Bond's Vortex does remind me of the book, it has the same "near future" vibe. I think the book I'm trying to find was written in the late 1970s or early 1980s.

Answer (score 7):

This is a long shot.  The only book I know of that has nukes in South African gold mines is [The Rock
by Bob Mayer](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10788659-the-rock).

From an [Amazon customer review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2DCIHAP7ZY2UH/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B004EPYZ2Q):

> A nuclear bomb is smuggled into one of South Africa's deepest mines,
> and when detonated, ends the gold production necessary to power much
> of Africa's economic development. However, that is not all it does.
> Then a strange message appears to come out of Ayer's Rock. This
> message is in a highly compressed and coded form, but when decoded,
> the decoders see that it is the message carried by Voyager 2, intended
> for the rest of the Universe, although at this stage, Voyager 2 is at
> about twice Pluto's distance. Then, quite out of place, the message
> ends with the names of four people. The book then focuses on the US
> authorities "collecting" these people, with or without their
> permission, and shipping them to Ayer's Rock.

Comment: That looks like an interesting book, but from the little I remember from that book I read 40 years ago it didn't have much technological science fiction elements, except that it took place in what was then the future.